# jQuery ajax serialize with variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, variables, serialization

I have a form that I'm submitting with jQuery ajax after validation checks. For some reason if I use a variable for the form ID in the data parameter the form data is not submitted. If I explicitly list the form ID the form is submitted without issue.

The $formID var is declared earlier in the code and it is not out of scope as it works for the url parameter but not the data parameter.

How can I use a variable here? What am I missing?

Here's what works:

```
 var submit = $.ajax({
    url: $($formID).attr('action'),
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('#gform_2').serialize(),
});
```

This does not work (using $formID variable):

```
 var submit = $.ajax({
    url: $($formID).attr('action'),
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $($formID).serialize(),
});
```

Nor does this (using this):

```
 var submit = $.ajax({
    url: $($formID).attr('action'),
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot the `#`

```
var submit = $.ajax({
    url: $($formID).attr('action'),
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('#' + $formID).serialize(),
});
```

then please share error console